# $O=\{x \in l_2(\mathbb{N}): \sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{x_j}{j} \neq 0\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

How can i show  that if $\ell_2(\mathbb{N)}=\{x: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C} :\sum_{j \geq1 } |x_j|^2  < \infty \}$ how can i show that  $O=\{x \in l_2(\mathbb{N}): \sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{x_j}{j} \neq 0\}$

$\ell_2(\mathbb{N)}=\{x: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C} :\sum_{j \geq1 } |x_j|^2  < \infty \}$

I know that if $x\in \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ then $\sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{x_j}{j}$ converges, but how this can help me to prove that $O$ is open

Answer (score 4):

The linear functional $T:\ell_2(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by

$$T(\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}) = \sum_{n=1}^n \frac{x_n}{n}$$

is bounded (continuous) by Cauchy-Schwarz. This implies that $O^c = T^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed and, therefore, that $O$ is open.